# Can I withdraw a conversion to a Roth IRA without penalty?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, withdrawal, roth-conversion

Several years ago I converted some money from both Traditional and SEP IRAs to my Roth IRA. I paid taxes on the money I converted at the time.

I know that a Roth IRA allows you to withdraw *contributions* at any time, without penalty, but am I also allowed to withdraw *conversions*?

Answer (score 4):

There is no tax on withdrawal of a conversion, but there is a [penalty](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b#en_US_2017_publink1000231065) on non-qualified distributions (i.e. before you are 59.5 years old) of a conversion within 5 years of the conversion (there is a separate 5-year period for each conversion), and the penalty is on the part of the conversion that was taxable. I am guessing your entire conversion was taxable, so the entire conversion would be subject to penalty if withdrawn within 5 years, unless you withdraw after age 59.5.